# How autocorrelation work based on the data plot?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, autocorrelation, data-mining, predictor

Let's suppose we have a time series is a=[1,1,1,3,3,3,1,1,1,3,3,3]  as
[image]

then the autocorrelation figure for this time series is
[image]

The lag here is 4, for lag = 1, the autocorrelation is between [1,1,1,3,3,3,1,1,1,3,3] and [1,1,3,3,3,1,1,1,3,3,3]. In order to not have overlap between data sets I add a constant number to the lagged version in the following figures
[image]

Then for lag = 2, the autocorrelation is between [1,1,1,3,3,3,1,1,1,3] and [1,3,3,3,1,1,1,3,3,3]
[image]

Then for lag= 3 the autocorrelation is between [1,1,1,3,3,3,1,1,1] and [3,3,3,1,1,1,3,3,3],
[image]

and finally for lag= 4 the autocorrelation is between [1,1,1,3,3,3,1,1] and [3,3,1,1,1,3,3,3]

[image]

Now, my question is that how one could associated the afc values to their plot? What I mean how correlation can be seen on their figure plot? The blue dots are the real data and other colors are the lagged data.